# Android keyboard cannot click through views

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I am developing a keyboard based on android LatinIME, the problem is that I cannot click on anything behind InputView. (In android keyboard this view is visible and clickable through when doing google search for example).

To be precise this is the view that can be clicked through in original keyboard from input-view.xml

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/key_preview_backing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/key_preview_backing_height" />
```

I turned on visual debug by setting sVISUALDEBUG in LatinIMELogger.java to true so I can see these are in transparent red.

Any possible suggestion about what can be broken so it works this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The problem was that in compatibility.`InputMethodService.Insets` in android 2.1 doesn't support `TOUCHABLE_INSETS_REGION` constant, so I had to changed it `TOUCHABLE_INSETS_VISIBLE` to enable clicking through invisible views of my keyboard (i.e. `SuggestionsView`)